# Recursive Array functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

The program finds the average length of words in a given input and prints the words greater than the average. Here's the program

```
#define STRING_LEN 80
#define ARRAY_LEN 3
void *emalloc(size_t s) {
    void *result = malloc(s);
    if (NULL == result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return result;
}


void numbers_greater(char **wordlist, int average, int n){

    if(n < ARRAY_LEN){
        int a = strlen(wordlist[n]);
        if(a>average){ 
            printf("%s", wordlist[n]);
        }
        numbers_greater(wordlist+1, average, n+1);
    }

 }


int main(void) {
    char word[STRING_LEN];
    char *wordlist[ARRAY_LEN];
    int num_words;
    double average;
    int i;

    while (num_words < ARRAY_LEN && 1 == scanf("%79s", word)) {
        wordlist[num_words] = emalloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof wordlist[0][0]);
        strcpy(wordlist[num_words], word);
        num_words++;
    }


    average = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
        average += strlen(wordlist[i]);
    }
    average = average / num_words;
    printf("%f\n", average);

    numbers_greater(wordlist, average, 0);



    for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
        free(wordlist[i]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The program works up until the "numbers_greater" method, giving a segmentation fault error. I'm new to C so I'm a little bit confused, the recursive method runs without an error without the strlen statement, but with the strlen statement (even if I set it to a static number like 2) it bombs out of the code. Am I traversing through the array incorrectly?

Comment: `num_words` is uninitialized.

Comment: what is the function print_stuff?

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be numbers_greater (I changed the names of the functions to improve readability)

Comment: A segfault often means that you are accessing an invalid pointer somewhere. I suggest that you use a debugger to step through your code to double-check what it is doing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the current version of your code. Any inconsistencies will cause much confusion which will only frustrate anyone who wants to help you. It will also waste a lot of your time, not to mention those of us who are willing to help.

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line

`numbers_greater(wordlist+1, average, n+1);`

will increment both the `wordlist` pointer and the integer `n`. What you are doing, in effect is incrementing the value you are checking by 2 instead of by one, as you would like to do.

To eliminate the segfault, change this line to the following:

`numbers_greater(wordlist, average, n + 1);`

As a note, this could be done much easier using a simple for loop. Also, I did not read the rest of the code and there may be some other error that I missed, but this should eliminate the segmentation fault in this function.

Answer (score 2):

Lets walk through

```
void numbers_greater(char **wordlist, int average, int n){

    if(n < ARRAY_LEN){
        int a = strlen(wordlist[n]);
        if(a>average){ 
            printf("%s", wordlist[n]);
        }
        numbers_greater(wordlist+1, average, n+1);
    }
}
```

I have an array of strings that can hold 3 things, and I put n = 1. It works the first time... but now we get to

```
numbers_greater(wordlist+1, average, n+1);
```

so now we have an array of strings that can hold 2 things because of the `wordlist+1` . n = 2 now , so `n < ARRAY_LEN` is true, but `wordlist[n]` will result in reading the 3rd element inside an array that should only hold 2.

To fix this try

```
numbers_greater(wordlist, average, n+1);
```